# Jump to end of line in nano command

Tags: bash, nano

I have an alias, that opens a file for me and jumps to a specific line in that file.

The first thing I do is ctrl+E to jump to the end of the line, but I was wondering if I can automate that as well?

This is the current alias:

> alias changeCust='ssh -t root@192.168.56.101 "nano +33
>   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/25-av_portal.conf && service apache2
>   reload"'

Answer (score 15):

Only answering **Jump to end of line in nano command** is

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

I do know, that this does not correctly answer the asked question. - But I was looking for the heading's question and this entry was the one found by google in the first place for me. And the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> is not good recognizable in the posted question for my fast eye-brain-learn-detection-mechanism.

fyi: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> jumps to the beginning.
I found it [here](http://harlankellaway.com/documents/nano_cheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You can open nano at line X column Y by calling nano like so:

```
nano +3,5 yourFile
```

This will open your file and place the cursor on line 3 column 5.

Not that on an Apple Mac, only the line number works, so adding `,5` will do nothing, you can only say

```
nano +3 yourFile
```